# How to properly import python-keycloak

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, keycloak

I am trying to use python-keycloak in visual studio code but i'm having the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keycloak
```

I've installed the package using pip:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-keycloak in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (0.17.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.20.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-keycloak) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-jose>=1.4.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-keycloak) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->python-keycloak) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->python-keycloak) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->python-keycloak) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->python-keycloak) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-jose>=1.4.0->python-keycloak) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future<1.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-jose>=1.4.0->python-keycloak) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-jose>=1.4.0->python-keycloak) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ecdsa<1.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-jose>=1.4.0->python-keycloak) (0.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from rsa->python-jose>=1.4.0->python-keycloak) (0.4.7)
```

And this is the line where i try to import the module:

```py
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
```

It is exactly how is described in the documentation, is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: do you have python3 installed?

Comment: Yes,this is the output of "py --version" ->
Python 3.7.4

Comment: please, enter python3 shell and type `import keycloak`. Was it imported successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[python-keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) package requires python3. 
Please try to enter python3 shell and try to run:

```
import keycloak
```

If it works, you installed the package successfully.

The problem is probably with Python version *visual studio code* uses.  Follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) to set correct Python version.

Comment: This helped me solve the issue. My pip was pointing to a Python 2.7 while my debugger was pointing to a Python 3.7. I added pip to the Py3.7 and imported the package correctly with it.